# React-Native Invariant Violation When Using Custom Input Component

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, input, components

I am in the beginning phase of building a react-native application and on my first screen I want to have custom input textfield.

As of right now, the code on the page will load if I try to put a regular text component by react-native but when I use the custom input component I created it throws an error that there is an invariant violation.

**Here is the setup of the custom input component:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native'

const InputCustom = ({label, placeholder, onChangeText,secureTextEntry,error,
    inputStyle, labelStyle,containerStyle,errorStyle,textAlign}) => {
        return(
            <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
            <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            autoCorrect={false}
            style={inputStyle}
            value={value}
            textAlign={textAlign}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            />
            <Text style={errorStyle}>{error}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    export {InputCustom};
```

**Here is the custom component being used in a custom view**

```js
import React from 'react'
import View from 'react-native'
import InputCustom from '/Users/tmi/Documents/Mobile Applications/myproject/src/components/common/InputCustom.js'

const CreateAccountTextFields = (props) => {
    return(
            <View>
            <View>
                <InputCustom
                label ="First Name"
                placeholder="First Name"
                value={props.firstName}
                inputStyle ={props.inputStyle}
                containerStyle={props.containerStyle}
                labelStyle={props.labelStyle}
                textAlign={props.textAlign}
                onChangeText={props.fNameOnChange}
                
            />
            </View>
            </View>
    )
}

export default CreateAccountTextFields
```

**Lastly, here is the page that would be viewed by the user that's throwing the actual error**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ScrollView  from 'react-native'
import {CreateAccountTextFields} from '/Users/tmi/Documents/Mobile Applications/myproject/src/components/applaunch/signup/CreateAccountTextFields.js'
import SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles from '../../styles/SignUp/SignUpTextFieldStyle.styles'

// This is the Sign Up Page a User will see on their screen with all elements added to this screen 

class SignUpView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            firstName: '',
        }
    }
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'The Test ',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'black'}, 
        headerTitleStyle: {color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Impact', fontSize: 30} ,
      };
      render(){
          return(
              <ScrollView>
                <CreateAccountTextFields
                firstName={"this.props.firstName"}
                inputStyle={SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles.shortInputStyle}
                containerStyle={SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles.shortInputContrainerStyle}
                labelStyle={SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles.shortInputLabelStyle}
                textAlign={SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles.inputTextAlign}
                errorStyle={SignUpTextFieldStyleStyles.error}
                />
            </ScrollView>
          )
      }
}
export default SignUpView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues off the bat with the code you posted, and I suspect you did not post all of the relevant code here, e.g. you are importing styles from somewhere that you did not provide. I copied your code into a fresh app and debugged until I got an invariant violation. I suspect it's the same one you're running into.

In this case, the violation is because you are importing defaults from `react-native` when you want to be importing specific components.

`import View from 'react-native'` should be `import { View } from 'react-native'`

`import ScrollView  from 'react-native'` should be `import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'`

In addition, as mentioned in another answer, you should export your custom components using `export default COMPONENT` and import them with `import COMPONENT from FILE`. Note that in this case we are not using `{}` to import the component.

I also ran into the missing `value` prop in the custom component args as mentioned in another comment. Full code of my repro here:

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import SignUpView from "./components/SignUpView";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SignUpView />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

`InputCustom.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native'

const InputCustom = ({label, placeholder, onChangeText,secureTextEntry,error, inputStyle, labelStyle,containerStyle,errorStyle,textAlign, value}) => {
    return(
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
            <TextInput
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                autoCorrect={false}
                style={inputStyle}
                value={value}
                textAlign={textAlign}
                onChangeText={onChangeText} />
            <Text style={errorStyle}>{error}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default InputCustom;
```

`CreateAccountTextFields.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import InputCustom from './InputCustom.js'

const CreateAccountTextFields = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <InputCustom
                label ="First Name"
                placeholder="First Name"
                value={props.firstName}
                inputStyle ={props.inputStyle}
                containerStyle={props.containerStyle}
                labelStyle={props.labelStyle}
                textAlign={props.textAlign}
                onChangeText={props.fNameOnChange} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default CreateAccountTextFields;
```

`SignUpView.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { ScrollView }  from 'react-native'
import CreateAccountTextFields from './CreateAccountTextFields.js'
import styles from '../styles/styles';

class SignUpView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            firstName: '',
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ScrollView>
              <CreateAccountTextFields
              firstName={"this.props.firstName"}
              inputStyle={styles.shortInputStyle}
              containerStyle={styles.shortInputContrainerStyle}
              labelStyle={styles.shortInputLabelStyle}
              textAlign={styles.inputTextAlign}
              errorStyle={styles.error}
              />
          </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
export default SignUpView;
```

`styles.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Moving the imported components into brackets fixed the issue. Thanks for you help Benjamin. Could you happen to point me into the right direction to learn more about importing defaults and what they are.

Comment: google `javascript default exports` for some good results. In particular https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you are using import, Use

```
export default InputCustom;
```

instead of

```
export {InputCustom};
```

Comment: The error still seems to be there after making the change suggested.

Comment: @AhmeeyaGoldman, Another thing, in custom component, `value` is declared in props list right?

Comment: Good catch @SivaKondapiVenkata it wasn't but the error hasn't gone away yet sadly.

Comment: I noticed that when I imported the InputCustom component into the SignUpView it loads so it must be something with how the CreateAccountTextFields view is transferring over the data.

Comment: oh, possible. Can you try `import CreateAccountTextFields from` instead of `import {CreateAccountTextFields} from`?

Comment: doesn't make a difference.